# How to display custom post type in a submenu?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugins, menus

I am adding a submenu named as "**Articles**" using **add_submenu_page()** under a custom menu. I want to display the custom post type="page_article" in this "Articles" submenu.

Whenever I click on Articles submenu , it should redirect me to "**edit.php?post_type="page_article**".

I have tried with wp_redirect in **callback function** of add_submenu_page, but I am not getting.

Thanks

Comment: Post your code that you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

Tried with this and got the solution

**add_submenu_page( 'page_main', "Articles",  "Articles" , 'adminstrator', 'edit.php?post_type=page_article' );**

Thanks